# MySQL password issues (mac OS X Lion)

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I am trying to set the root password for MySQL in the terminal in Mac OS X Lion, and I am having issues. Every time I use the line:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password ******  (where ****** is the password I want to set)
```

I receive the error:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I have not set a password previously, so I do not know why I am receiving this error.

Comment: are you changing old password or creating password first time?

Answer (score 37):

Here is the procedure to reset password of root user.

1) Stop mysql (Kill mysql process or run following command)

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

2) Start it in safe mode

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

3) Open another terminal and run the following command (Keep last terminal open)

```
mysql -u root
```

4) Run the following command with suitable new password on the mysql console

For MySQL 5.7+:

```
mysql > UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

For earlier versions:

```
mysql > UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

5) `mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

6) Quit from both terminals and open new terminal and connect to mysql with root user and new password

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: I get this error after I type in 1): "ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!"

Comment: FYI: on newer mysql versions the `password` field has been renamed to `authentication_string`.

Comment: @minhas2 Yours is the only solution that has worked after 2 hours of frustration. Thanks :)

Comment: getting error unknown column password

Comment: I deleted the folder "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql" and installed mysql again, after the installation is generated a new password

Answer (score 23):

Type:`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password`

When it asks for a password, not not enter anything, just hit enter.
It will then ask you to enter new password, then confirm.
Finished.

Comment: Works like a charm (Mac OS X Lion)

Comment: Not working for me. Still: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Answer (score 6):

for creating password first time use

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

updating old password use

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass
```

Source = http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/

Comment: really?  after what I just typed?  You give the same answer?  It's not WORKING!  I want to create a password for the first time.  The most progress I've gotten is I've typed: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password and then I am prompted with Enter Password:  .... however, it won't allow me to type (no type appears in the terminal for the enter password line).  Then when I try to type it and hit enter it now gives me the error: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: it seems you have created password and mysql is asking you to login with that password. i assume you dont remember the password since you created by mistake. you need to reset this password. visit this link on how to reset password for mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Following the 'Unix' instructions, I cannot find the .pid file on my system.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I found the file, but when I type in:  shell> kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/(my host_name).pid ...into terminal, I get the following error:

Comment: cat: /mysql-data-directory/(my host_name).pid: No such file or directory
-bash: shell: command not found

Comment: i dont have mac os to help you directly....check this link http://serverfault.com/questions/67111/reset-mysql-5-root-password-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Yosemite, but on Maverick has the same problem.
- Fix the 2002 socket error first if you haven’t done

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

An then try

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer man! You can't imagine how much this helped me. I found two solutions for my problems in one answer.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how you set the password. That is how you login to mysql.

If you don't have a password set, you login using:

```
mysql -u root
```

and that will get you to the MySQL command line.

Instead of doing that just use the following to change the password.

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Comment: when I type in just mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD into terminal, I receive the line: -bash: mysqladmin command not found

Comment: and what you just typed, Kayak, is EXACTLY what I typed in the question, I continue to receive the error, it won't let me set a password using that command

Comment: when I use mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass I receive the same error message, however, it now says "using Password:YES"

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin

./mysqladmin -u root password root
```

Answer (score 1):

To set your root password after installing:

1. Ensure MySQL is not running, stop it if you ran it.
2. On a Terminal do `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` to run MySQL bypassing the authentication.
3. Inside mysql do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
4. Then reset by `SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');` where 'password' is your chosen password.
5. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` one more time

Answer (score 0):

This fix it for me:
After this is going to ask you for your Super User password and then for the new password.

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password

Comment: I just get the error again after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to reset or set a new root password?

Steps for **MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier**:

Open a Terminal Window:

1. Stop mysql server if it is running:

   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
2. Restart it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option:

   `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

Open another Terminal Window:

3. Type:
    `mysql -u root`
4. Reset root password (i.e. for localhost)

   `UPDATE mysql.user 
       SET authentication_string = PASSWORD(‘MyNewPass’), password_expired = 'N'
       WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Now your password for root@localhost is *MyNewPass*. You can change it:

5. Close all Terminal Windows. Open a new Terminal Window and type:

   `mysqladmin -u root -p'MyNewPass' password '123456'`

   Now your root password is *123456*

   You should see below warning message, you can ignore it if you are changing your root@localhost password:

   > mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface
   >   can be insecure. Warning: Since password will be sent to server in
   >   plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
6. Check if your root password is successfully changed:

   `mysql -u root -p'123456' -e 'show databases;'`

   Output:

   > mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be
   >   insecure.
   >
   > +--------------------+
   >   | Database           |
   >   +--------------------+
   >   | information_schema |
   >   | mysql              |
   >   | performance_schema |
   >   | sys                |
   >   +--------------------+

Answer (score 0):

This is working on macOS Sierra

step 1:  open terminal

step 2:  paste the following command

```
     sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

Your terminal should show this :

```
     Users-MacBook-Air:~ usr$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

Password:
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

Starting MySQL
.. SUCCESS!

Step 3:  Make sure SQL server is running

Step 4:  Open the MYSQL working and click the local instance

Step 5: type old password and new password

Answer (score 0):

You will lose all databases

step 1: open terminal

step 2: delete folder mysql
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql`

step 3: installed mysql again, after the installation is generated a new password

Answer (score -2):

Step 1:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It will ask
Enter password:

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.

You can check default databases

```
mysql> show databases;
mysql> show tables;
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the question. The question is not about how to login into mysql which you have provided the command `mysql -u root -p` but how to change the user password with `mysqladmin`