# mysqld_safe Command issues

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm fairly new to mysql and terminal use, so please bear with me. I am trying to log in to mysql through the terminal on my mac, but it continually says Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) or (using password: NO). I have tried using the following passwords:

- The password given to me when I downloaded MySQL Community Server (I received a pop-up that gave me a temp password)
- 'root'
- My Mac password
- No password

While searching for the problem, I came across multiple articles saying to reset the password ([here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541115/mysql-password-issues-mac-os-x-lion)). They say to reset the password, you must stop the mysql server, and type in

> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables.

The issue is, when I type that command in, it still asks for a password, but as I understand, [it should bypass asking for a password and let you set a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896082/stuck-with-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-terminal-mac). After I enter the above set of possible of passwords (again, I don't know what it should be), it tells me the command is not found. Please let me know if I am wrong or what I can do to remedy this.

Comment: Download a copy of mysqlworkbench. see if you can start a server instance and look for user privs.

Comment: Hey thanks, apparently I had to start an instance of mysqlworkbench and log in there with the temp password once, then it prompted me to change the root password. If you would like to make this an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a copy of mysqlworkbench. Start a server instance and look for user privs.